# How to prefer table name over column when names collide (in postgres)

Tags: postgresql

Postgres allows

```
select row_to_json(table_name) from table_name;
```

which provides a json map for each record in the table.

However if the table has a column that is the same name as the table, for reasons best left known only to the language designers, postgres prefers the column name, not the table name and complains that the parameter to row_to_json is the wrong type (not a record).

Is there a way to say that the name should refer to a table, and not the column?

(Their choice here is a little annoying since if the table name had higher visibility, we could disambiguate with tablename.columnname).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select row_to_json(t) 
from table_name t
```

or

```
select row_to_json(table_name.*)
from table_name
```

Notice that while the above will return the actual table columns as key names the `row` construct will not as it creates an anonymous record type as in:

```
select row_to_json(row(table_name.*))
from table_name
```

Comment: According to the manual, you don't need the double brackets around `table_name.*`, as this isn't technically a row constructor, just a special-case syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This case is actually [discussed in the manual under the heading "Using Composite Types in Queries"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE).

> Note however that simple names are matched to column names before table names, so this example works only because there is no column named c in the query's tables.

The solution is that `table_name.*` is automatically expanded in various contexts, just like it would be in a normal `SELECT` query. The manual gives an explicit example of using it with a function:

> For example, if somefunc() accepts a composite-valued argument, these queries are the same:

```
SELECT somefunc(c.*) FROM inventory_item c;
SELECT somefunc(c) FROM inventory_item c;
```

It goes on to say:

> In particular, the parser will consider c in c.* to refer to a table name or alias, not to a column name, so that there is no ambiguity; whereas without .*, it is not clear whether c means a table name or a column name, and in fact the column-name interpretation will be preferred if there is a column named c.

So in short, the solution to your problem is to write this:

```
select row_to_json(table_name.*) from table_name;
```

Comment: row_to_json(table_name) seems to be valid with table names -- its only a problem because of the name collision.

Comment: @user48956 Yes, I understand the problem, and this syntax provides a solution to that problem. I've actually found a better manual page which directly refers to your situation, so I've edited my answer substantially.